# links on RSS reader are not working very well

Tags: discussion, bug, rss

I am using [this RSS reader](https://feeder.co/) but it is days that it is not working very well. For example I am following [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/331/jason-devito) and today it has been notified to me that he has an activity with the following link to that activity:
[Homotopic function question - very basic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799499/homotopic-function-question-very-basic/3809445#3809445)

which is not refer to comment. In the timeline list of that post, the correct comment link is as follows:

[Homotopic function question - very basic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799499/homotopic-function-question-very-basic/3809445#comment7858378_3809445)

This was not the case before last update I think. Is it bug of my RSS reader?

Comment: This is a (very old) bug in the RSS feed: [Use comment permalinks where appropriate in in user RSS feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122966/295232). There's nothing wrong with your reader.

Comment: But that was fine a few weeks ago!!

Comment: This means that no solution has been founded so far?

Comment: There's no solution and no way that this was working fine before :)

Comment: So why developers don't use SE notification link (which works correctly) to RSS link?

Comment: e.g. : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/145074?noredirect=1

Comment: I don't understand!! Why they can add the comment exact link to `timeline` history or to SE notification bar, but they can't add it to RSS? very ODD problem.

Comment: The number of people using RSS feeds is quite low, apparently the bug is not important enough.

Comment: :( . I am not important! :(

Comment: Is it possible for developers or moderators to see how many users are using from RSS?

Comment: They'd probably have to track access to the feed url by unique IP's... I'd be surprised if anyone was doing that.